# javascript function stops when using window.location

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to coding, and I am trying to develop some sort of a simple board game.

I have two pages, on the first one, I have a list where one should choose the number of players, then click on a button that will run a function to open a second page and display the number of players.

The problem is when the function is runnig, it seems to stop at window.location, which makes sense. Is there a way that my function could keep running even after the page has changed ?

Below are my two pages and my js code simplified to include only the element that are part of my problem.

```
function chooseNbrPlayers(){
window.location.href = "page2.html"; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("selectNbrPlayers").selectedIndex;
var nbrPlayers =  document.getElementById("selectNbrPlayers").selectedIndex;
    }


<html>
<head>
    <title>page1</title>

    <p><button onclick="chooseNbrPlayers()">Play</button></p>
        <body>
            <form><select id="selectNbrPlayers">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>1 player</option>
                    <option>2 players</option>
                    <option>3 players</option>
                    <option>4 players</option>
                    </select>
            </form>
        </body>
        <script src=script.js></script>
</head>
</html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>page2</title>

    <p>There are <span id="demo"></span> players.</p>

        <script src=script.js></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: *Is there a way my function could keep running*, we would need a desired behavior for this. You are routing to a new page. Do you want your script to run there? or do you want to open the URL on next page and keep script running?

Comment: Do you want to open the URL in new tab?

Comment: can you upload a fiddle?

Comment: Your function just writes output to a specific element and then declares a variable it never uses.  Exactly what do you want this to do when the page is unloaded?  What output are you expecting to see in an element that's no longer in the browser?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'd want to open the url in the same tab. I'd want to run my script on both pages. Basically all I need is to store the number of players in a variable that I can access in the second page. Sorry I really am a beginner and my understanding is very limited :)

Comment: If you would like a certain piece of JavaScript code to run after the `window.location.href`, you should add that specific code to the very next page your JavaScript function will send you to and call for the function containing that code. You could also make a general function in a general javascript and add the same script with the same function to both pages.

Comment: @CorentinFleur: If you want code to execute on `page2.html` then that code needs to be on `page2.html`.  Your next question then becomes, how can you send a value to that next page?  You can include that value on the URL, store it in local storage, etc.

Comment: I managed to find a solution with the local storage solution, that's sort of what I was looking for, sorry for bad explanation of my problem! thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

Your js code retry in any situation, when you redirect at new page. Script.js launch again begin. I think better choice it's a routing. 
You can write specific scripts for different pages, but i think it's incorrect.